# Show that convergence in distribution implies convergence of moments

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I'm trying to show that convergence in distribution implies convergence of moments under some conditions. In particular consider Lemma 2.21 of van der Vaart p. 18

> Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n
>  \rightarrow_d X$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n|^p<\infty$ for
>   some $p>0$. Then [...] $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(|X_n|^k)-E(|X|^k)$
>    $\forall k <p$.

The first step of the proof is obscure to me. The author says that by Markov's inequality
$$
E(|X_n|^k 1\{|X_n|^k\geq M\})\leq M^{1-\frac{p}{k}}E(|X_n|^p)
$$

Could you help me to clarify it?

My attempt so far:

> (1) $P(|X_n|\geq \tilde{M})=P(|X_n|^k\geq \tilde{M^k})\leq
>  \frac{E(|X_n|^k)}{\tilde{M}^k}$ by Markov's inequality $\forall
>  \tilde{M}>0$
>
> (2) define $M:=\tilde{M}^k$ and rewrite $P(|X_n|^k\geq M)\leq
>  \frac{E(|X_n|^k)}{M}$
>
> (3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that  $$\tag{*}1\{|X_n|^k\geqslant M\}\frac{|X_n|}{ M^{1/k} }\geqslant1\{|X_n|^k\geqslant M\} .  $$ Indeed, if $|X_n|^k\lt M$, this equality reads $0=0$, while if $|X_n|^k\geqslant M$, the inequality is equiavalent to  $|X_n|\geqslant M^{1/k}$, which is true.

Now take the power $p-k$ in both sides of (*) and multiply by $|X_k|$ in order to get

$$|X_n|^k 1\{|X_n|^k\geqslant M\}\leqslant \left(\frac{|X_n|}{ M^{1/k} }  \right)^{p-k}|X_n|^k 1\{|X_n|^k\geqslant M\}.$$
The wanted inequality follows by integrating and rearranging the exponents.

Comment: Thanks but it is still obscure. Could you add more steps? (1) Since $1\{|X_n|^k \geq M\} \frac{|X_n|}{M^{\frac{1}{k}}}\geq 1\{|X_n|^k \geq M \}$: why? (2) How do you get the main expression above? (3) How do you get the wanted inequality from the inequality above?

Comment: I have added more details.